# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unsupported marker type 0x03

Tags: php, image, apache, caching, imagick

I have problem with Imagick. I have two servers. One production and one dev. When I run the `$imagick = new Imagick(); $imagick->readImage($_img);` on my production server, everything works fine. But When I run it on my dev server, I got the error message: `"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message'Unsupported marker type 0x03"`.

The image is on both servers identical. 
Have you met with someone?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify that the images that are used on dev server are not corrupted?

Comment: The images are identical on both server. So when on first server it works, it must works on second server too. Or not?